# How can I create several ebs volumes each of a different size using a map in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a terraform tfvars file with a map of values that looks like this:

```
name_map = [
  {
    name         = "devbox"
    device_names = ["/dev/xvdg", "/dev/xvdh"]
    volume_size = ["900", "200"]
    group        = "hosts"
    instance_type = "m5a.2xlarge"
  },
  {
    name         = "devbox2"
    device_names = ["/dev/xvdg", "/dev/xvdh"]
    volume_size = ["300", "200"]
    group        = "hosts"
    instance_type = "m5a.2xlarge"
  }
]
```

]
My tf file looks like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "node" {
  count         = length(var.name_map)

  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = [for device in var.name_map.*.device_names[count.index] : {
      device_name = device,
      volume_size = var.name_map.*.volume_size[count.index]
    }]
    content {
      device_name           = ebs_block_device.value.device_name
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      volume_size           = ebs_block_device.value.volume_size
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }
```

So basically for the "devbox" instance I'd like "/dev/xvdg" to be 900 gbs, and "/dev/xvdh" to be 200 gbs. I'd like The current setup works to iterate through the device names of each mapping and get a single volume size but I'm trying to expand it to include different volume sizes for each device.

How would I do this?

I've tried a nested for_each statement but I keep getting errors. Would a flatten structure be the solution here? I'd love to see an example of what this would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "node" {
  count = length(var.name_map)

  instance_type = var.name_map[count.index].instance_type
  ami = "..." # Fill in a valid AMI here

  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = [for i, device in var.name_map[count.index].device_names : {
      device_name = device,
      volume_size = var.name_map[count.index].volume_size[i]
    }]
    content {
      device_name           = ebs_block_device.value.device_name
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      volume_size           = ebs_block_device.value.volume_size
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }
}
```

While this works, I suggest you do the following:

```
variable "name_map" {
  default = [
    {
      name = "devbox"
      devices = [
        {
          device_name = "/dev/xvdg",
          volume_size = 900
        },
        {
          device_name = "/dev/xvdh",
          volume_size = 200
        }
      ]
      group         = "hosts"
      instance_type = "m5a.2xlarge"
    },
    {
      name = "devbox2"
      devices = [
        {
          device_name = "/dev/xvdg",
          volume_size = 900
        },
        {
          device_name = "/dev/xvdh",
          volume_size = 200
        }
      ]
      group         = "hosts"
      instance_type = "m5a.2xlarge"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note, the `device_name` and the `volume_size` are grouped together. Now we can use a simple `foor` loop where we don't have to rely on indexing:

```
resource "aws_instance" "node" {
  count = length(var.name_map)

  instance_type = var.name_map[count.index].instance_type
  ami           = "..." # fill in a valid AMI name

  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    # Notice the i variable (index) was dropped here
    for_each = [for device in var.name_map[count.index].devices : {
      device_name = device.device_name,
      volume_size = device.volume_size
    }]
    content {
      device_name           = ebs_block_device.value.device_name
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      volume_size           = ebs_block_device.value.volume_size
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. Removing the extra index was much easier than what I was attempting.

Answer (score 0):

I would nest your map further to create something like this:

```
name_map = [
  {
    name         = "devbox"
    root_block_device = {
      ...settings
    }
    ebs_block_devices = toSet([
      {
        name = "/dev/xvdg"
        size = "900"
      },{
        name = "/dev/xvdh"
        size = "200"
      }
    ])
    group        = "hosts"
    instance_type = "m5a.2xlarge"
  },
  ...
]
```

and then in your resource code you can loop over the set for each instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  count = length(var.name_map)

  ...

  root_block_device {
    ...settings from var.name_map[count.index].root_block_device
  }

  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = var.name_map[count.index].ebs_block_devices

    content {
      device_name = ebs_block_device.value.name
      volume_size = ebs_block_device.value.size
    }
  }
}
```

If you want the root volume to persist post termination I would suggest adding an EBS root volume, otherwise you can ignore the root_block_device and it will create an ephemeral device that contains the image.